# Recorrer elemento javaScript o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente elemento Array, que obtengo en una clase IEnumerable de ASP.NET, pero no he logrado obtener sus items.

```html
0: {Numero: "1111111", Item: "123", Text1: "Value1", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}
1: {Numero: "2222222", Item: "1234", Text1: "Value2", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}
2: {Numero: "3333333", Item: "12345", Text1: "Value3", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}
3: {Numero: "4444444", Item: "123456", Text1: "Value4", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}
4: {Numero: "5555555", Item: "1234567", Text1: "Value5", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}
```

Eso es lo que obtengo en la consola, el 0,1,2,3,4,5 son las posiciones de mi array.
He tratado de obtener el valor de elemento, ejemplo el valor de numero, item, text1.
Lo intento realizar de la siguiente manera:

```html
function createTemplates(stocks)
{
    $.each(stocks, function () {
      console.log($(this).find("Numero").text());
      console.log($(this).find("Item").text());
      console.log($(this).find("Text1").text());
      console.log($(this).find("Text2").text());
      console.log($(this).find("Qty").text());
    });
}
```

Pueden guiarme sobre como obtener los valores que deseo>?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías cambiar el each por un for utilizándolo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var element = [{Numero: "1111111", Item: "123", Text1: "Value1", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}, {Numero: "2222222", Item: "1234", Text1: "Value2", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}]

for ( var i = 0, l = element.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    console.log(element[i].Item);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

También podrías usar un ciclo for...of, para recorrer cada elemento de la lista, y adentro un for...in, para recorrer cada propiedad del elemento:

```js
var elements = [{Numero: "1111111", Item: "123", Text1: "Value1", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}, {Numero: "2222222", Item: "1234", Text1: "Value2", Text2: "/M", Qty: 0}]

for (let element of elements) {
  for (let prop in element) {
    console.log(element[prop]);
  }
}
```